# how to instantiate a template in apache nifi via rest api

Tags: api, deployment, automation, apache-nifi

i am trying to automate a deployment of apache nifi process-groups.

The steps i have working are:

- create snippet
- create template
- download template
- upload template

Then i am trying to use api call:

(https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/rest-api/)

POST     /process-groups/{id}/template-instance   Instantiates a template

```
   instantiate_data = { 
        "originX": 0.0,    
        "originY": 0.0,
        "templateId": template_id,      
        "snippet": { 
            "processGroups": [                  
                { 
                    "id": group_id,                 
                    "parentGroupId": parentgroup_id,
                    "position": {                       
                        "x": 0.0,                       
                        "y": 0.0                    
                    },
                    "name": "value",            
                }
                ] 
            } 
    }
```

And this is when i get a 500 from Nifi instance.

Stacktrace below... What am i missing?

```
2017-05-23 14:28:49,180 INFO [NiFi Web Server-106]       org.apache.nifi.web.filter.RequestLogger Attempting request for (anonymous) POST http://10.132.0.22:8080/nifi-api/process-groups/1664cd1a-015c-1000-4bbe-f63259900964/template-instance (source ip: 10.132.0.23)
```

2017-05-23 14:28:49,185 ERROR [NiFi Web Server-106] o.a.nifi.web.api.config.ThrowableMapper An unexpected error has occurred: java.lang.NullPointerException. Returning Internal Server Error response.
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.FlowController.verifyProcessorsInSnippet(FlowController.java:2051)
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.FlowController.lambda$verifyProcessorsInSnippet$1(FlowController.java:2067)
    at java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75)
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.FlowController.verifyProcessorsInSnippet(FlowController.java:2066)
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.FlowController.verifyComponentTypesInSnippet(FlowController.java:2100)
    at org.apache.nifi.web.dao.impl.StandardTemplateDAO.verifyComponentTypes(StandardTemplateDAO.java:74)
    at org.apache.nifi.web.dao.impl.StandardTemplateDAO$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$58f5765d.invoke()
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:720)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:655)
    at org.apache.nifi.web.dao.impl.StandardTemplateDAO$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$2cf2c182.verifyComponentTypes()
    at org.apache.nifi.web.StandardNiFiServiceFacade.verifyComponentTypes(StandardNiFiServiceFacade.java:1643)
    at org.apache.nifi.web.StandardNiFiServiceFacade$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$358780e0.invoke()
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:720)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.proceed(MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.java:85)
    at org.apache.nifi.web.NiFiServiceFacadeLock.proceedWithReadLock(NiFiServiceFacadeLock.java:137)
    at org.apache.nifi.web.NiFiServiceFacadeLock.verifyLock(NiFiServiceFacadeLock.java:126)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor320.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethodWithGivenArgs(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:621)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethod(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:610)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAroundAdvice.invoke(AspectJAroundAdvice.java:68)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:655)
    at org.apache.nifi.web.StandardNiFiServiceFacade$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$9a341d03.verifyComponentTypes()
    at org.apache.nifi.web.api.ProcessGroupResource.lambda$instantiateTemplate$41(ProcessGroupResource.java:1995)
    at org.apache.nifi.web.api.ApplicationResource.withWriteLock(ApplicationResource.java:667)
    at org.apache.nifi.web.api.ProcessGroupResource.instantiateTemplate(ProcessGroupResource.java:1967)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor327.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$ResponseOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:205)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:302)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1542)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1473)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1419)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1409)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:409)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:558)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:733)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:841)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1634)
    at org.apache.nifi.web.filter.RequestLogger.doFilter(RequestLogger.java:66)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1621)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:316)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:126)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:90)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:122)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.apache.nifi.web.security.NiFiAuthenticationFilter.authenticate(NiFiAuthenticationFilter.java:83)
    at org.apache.nifi.web.security.NiFiAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(NiFiAuthenticationFilter.java:57)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.apache.nifi.web.security.NiFiAuthenticationFilter.authenticate(NiFiAuthenticationFilter.java:83)
    at org.apache.nifi.web.security.NiFiAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(NiFiAuthenticationFilter.java:57)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.apache.nifi.web.security.NiFiAuthenticationFilter.authenticate(NiFiAuthenticationFilter.java:83)
    at org.apache.nifi.web.security.NiFiAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(NiFiAuthenticationFilter.java:57)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:213)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:176)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1621)
    at org.apache.nifi.web.filter.TimerFilter.doFilter(TimerFilter.java:51)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1613)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:541)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:548)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:190)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1593)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:188)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1239)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:168)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:481)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1562)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:166)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:118)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.gzip.GzipHandler.handle(GzipHandler.java:561)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:564)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:320)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:251)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:279)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.Invocable.invokePreferred(Invocable.java:122)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecutingExecutionStrategy.invoke(ExecutingExecutionStrategy.java:58)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.produceConsume(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:201)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.run(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:133)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:672)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:590)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Comment: Which version of NiFi are you using?  Is it the same version used to create the template?  Have you been able to manually deploy the template in the UI?  If so, you should be able to capture the API call in your browser's network debugging tools.  If not, I recommend trying to make a new, simpler template and trying it for comparison.

Comment: Just do what you need through the browser and trace all api requests with FireBug or DevTools whatever you use. Then just repeat the sequence of api calls from your implementation. If api calls works from browser then it should work from your code.

Comment: thanks alot! the eavesdropping on API calls from UI is a blessing :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@strzelecki.maciek,

You have to pass instantiate_data to be correctly like below.,

If any parameter belongs to instantiate data wrong then you receive 500 Internal Server error.

**Rest API URL:**

```
http://localhost:8080/nifi-api/process-groups/015c100c-8968-18bb-9b56-bf5342d001fd/template-instance
```

**with following instantiate data correctly.**

```
{
    "originX": 2.0,
    "originY": 3.0,
    "templateId": "87fb53bb-a4bd-4051-a129-66b29dfce2b4"
}
```

let me know if you face any issues.